# How do i make the variable lose 5% of its value?

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so I'm currently making a batch rpg and I want to make it so you lose 5% of your max health if you die.

This is the code i have for the health loss:

```
set /a healthmaxloss=5 / 100 * %healthmax%
set /a healthmax=%healthmax%-%healthmaxloss%
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I'm currently making a batch-rpg" - that's pretty messed-up...

Comment: @Dai it's the only software that our school computers can run so I thought it would be fun to do during class.

Comment: @rojo I had no idea how much it mattered! I can't upvote right now because of my reputation being too low but in the future I'll be sure to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /a healthmaxloss=(5 * healthmax) / 100
```

or

```
set /a healthmaxloss=healthmax / 20
```

Since batch-maths is integer, it's important that you don't attempt to generate fractions. As your expression stands, it would attempt to perform the division before the multiplication.

`set /a` doesn't require variable names in `%`.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be easier to make healthmax 95% of its previous value, rather than calculating 5% then subtracting.

```js
set /a healthmax = healthmax * 95 / 100
```